# What proportion of the people who lived 1000 years ago have genetic descendants alive today?

Tags: population-genetics, human-evolution, population-dynamics, population-biology

For context, I've been wondering about this for a paper I'm writing (in philosophy). Really, I want to figure out the chances that someone alive today will end up still having descendants 1000 years in the future. But people from 1000 years ago should be a good approximation.

So, any ideas? And are there any published papers which talk about this?

Comment: This related question would be a place to start https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/what-is-the-percentage-of-people-living-in-england-in-1500-ad-whose-lineage-is-s?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not a full answer, but I post it as one because the reasoning is too long to post it as a comment.**

You can make a rough estimation using a few assumptions.

1) Let's say 1 generation = 25 years, so 1000 years are 40 generations.

2) Let's say that half of the population is able to leave offspring, so the probability of one individual having descendants = 0.5

3) Supposing that the average number of siblings is 3.

- The probability of not having descendants in the 2nd generation  = 0.5
- The probability of not having descendants in the 3rd generation is 0.5*(1-0.5^3) = 0.4375

After the 3rd generation, it becomes a combinatorial problem that is too hard for me. I can tell that the probability of not having offsprings, giving that it already has, is going to 0 because of the number of offspring > 2

If this approach appears useful, I suggest you ask for a more complete solution on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @heracho's answer and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process), assume *p<sub>i</sub>* denotes the probability of having (exactly) *i* children, and that *d<sub>m</sub>* denotes the probability of extinction by the *m*th generation (note that this includes extinctions by all generations *n* with *n* < *m*). Then *d<sub>m</sub>* can be expressed as:

$\displaystyle d_m = p_0 + p_1 d_{m-1} + p_2 d_{m-1}^2 + p_3 d_{m-1}^3 + \dots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty p_i d_{m-1}^i$

with *d*<sub>0</sub> = 0.

In other words, the probability of going extinct by the *m*th generation is equal to the probability of *i* children going extinct in *m* – 1 generations, summed over *i*. (The child lineages are assumed independent.) This recurrence relation allows you to calculate the extinction (and, by extension, survival) probability at any desired number of generations, if the values of *p<sub>i</sub>* are known. In simple cases it is also possible to work out the asymptotic value of *d<sub>m</sub>* by solving the fixed point equation *d<sub>m</sub>* = *d*<sub>*m* – 1</sub> (see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process) for an example).

In relation to your specific application, we can assume roughly 40 generations and use some empirical estimates of *p<sub>i</sub>*. The parity distribution of Denmark is given by Frejka (2008) as *p*<sub>0</sub> = 0.127, *p*<sub>1</sub> = 0.179, *p*<sub>2</sub> = 0.443, *p*<sub>3</sub> = 0.251 (where I simplify by assuming that people who have strictly more than 3 children actually have only 3 children). Plugging these parameters into the recurrence relation and iterating for 40 generations (see R code below), we get *d*<sub>40</sub> = 0.17. Thus some 83% of the population can be assumed to have descendants in 1000 years.

I have taken Denmark as an example simply because it is the first country mentioned in Table 2 of Frejka (2008). However, to illustrate the dependence of the asymptotic value of *d<sub>m</sub>* on the parity parameters consider the case of Italy. From the same publication, we find *p*<sub>0</sub> = 0.240, *p*<sub>1</sub> = 0.235, *p*<sub>2</sub> = 0.369, *p*<sub>3</sub> = 0.156. With these values, we compute *d*<sub>40</sub> = 0.41, obviously a very different situation.

I am not a mathematician, nor a biologist (nor a demographer), and the above logic obviously employs many ridiculous simplifications. It would be very interesting to know how all this pans out in a more realistic model.

## Reference

Frejka, Tomas (2008) Parity distribution and completed family size in Europe: Incipient decline of the two-child family model? *Demographic Research*, 19(4): 47–72. https://www.demographic-research.org/volumes/vol19/4/19-4.pdf

## R code

```
# get extinction probability (d) in generation m, given extinction
# probability in generation m-1, conditioned on probabilities
# of having 0, 1, 2, ... children (vector p)
extinctionprob <- function(d, p) {
  d <- d^(0:(length(p)-1))
  sum(d*p)
}

# iterate for 'ngen' generations
iterate <- function(ngen, p) {
  d <- 0
  for (i in 1:ngen) d <- extinctionprob(d, p)
  d
}

# usage example:
# iterate(ngen=40, p=c(0.240, 0.235, 0.369, 0.156))
```